# Query to structure the table in a way to show the data in columns to row in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an employee details related table with all the details are categorized in a columnar way and i want to put that details according to date in a single row.

Employee details table:

```
-----------|------------|----------------|------------------|--|-- 

WORKER     | TRANSDATE  | EMPLCHANGETYPE | Employee details |  |
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 5              | TL               |  |  
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 3              | HR               |  |  
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 9              | Gurgaon          |  | 
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 6              | Ram              |  | 
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 8              | Active           |  | 
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 4              | TL               |  |
5637158890 | 06/08/2018 | 6              | Ravi             |  | 
5637158890 | 03/12/2018 | 9              | Gurgaon          |  | 
5637158890 | 03/12/2018 | 6              | Sam              |  | 
5637158890 | 05/04/2019 | 8              | Inactive         |  |
```

Expected Output:

```
  EmployeeID  | TRANSDATE  | Department | Employee status | Designation | Manager 
  5637158890  | 28/06/2018 | HR         | Active          | TL          | Ram     
  5637158890  | 06/08/2018 | HR         | Active          | TL          | Ravi    
  5637158890  | 03/12/2018 | HR         | Active          | TL          | Sam     
  5637158890  | 05/04/2019 | HR         | Inactive        | TL          | Sam
```

**Also would like to know how to fill in the null value with previous rows values.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    worker employeeID,
    transdate,
    max(case when emplchangetype = 3 then employee_details end) department,
    max(case when emplchangetype = 8 then employee_details end) status,
    max(case when emplchangetype = 5 then employee_details end) designation,
    max(case when emplchangetype = 6 then employee_details end) manager
from employee 
group by worker, transdate
```

Comment: thanks. Is there a way in Sql to fill up the null with value from above rows..

Comment: since i was not able to ask another question, i asked it in comments

Answer (score 0):

You can get arranged data according to date through this query:

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeDetails ORDER BY TRANSDATE ASC
```

And can insert it to a single row by `INSERT` query of SQL

The easiest way which may work!

Answer (score 0):

Based on `[Employee Details]` column you may add AGGREGATION CONDITION.

I created the sample table below and tried to get your expected output.

**Table: Employees**

```
WORKER     | TRANSDATE  | EMPLCHANGETYPE | EmployeeDetails
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 5              | TL              
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 3              | HR              
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 9              | Gurgaon         
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 6              | Ram             
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 8              | Active          
5637158890 | 28/06/2018 | 4              | TL              
5637158890 | 06/08/2018 | 6              | Ravi            
5637158890 | 03/12/2018 | 9              | Gurgaon         
5637158890 | 03/12/2018 | 6              | Sam             
5637158890 | 05/04/2019 | 8              | Inactive
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
   WORKER,
   TRANSDATE,
   Max(case when row_no=1 then Employeedetails end )as EmpDetails_1,
   Max(case when row_no=2 then Employeedetails end )as EmpDetails_2,
   Max(case when row_no=3 then Employeedetails end )as EmpDetails_3,
   Max(case when row_no=4 then Employeedetails end )as EmpDetails_4
FROM 
  (
      SELECT WORKER,TRANSDATE,Employeedetails,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY WORKER,TRANSDATE order by WORKER,TRANSDATE Desc) as row_no
      FROM Employees
  )
as EmployeesNew
group By WORKER,TRANSDATE
```

**Output:**

```
WORKER      |TRANSDATE  |EmpDetails_1|EmpDetails_2|EmpDetails_3|EmpDetails_4
5637158890  |03/12/2018 |Gurgaon     |  Sam     |(null)     |(null)
5637158890  |05/04/2019 |Inactive    |  (null)  |(null)     |(null)
5637158890  |06/08/2018 |Ravi        |  (null)  |(null)     |(null)
5637158890  |28/06/2018 |TL          |  HR      |Gurgaon    |Ram
```